# MapServer Shapefiles Not Displaying

Tags: mapserver, geoext, linux

I am current developing an GeoExt app which is up and running. Now I want to create maps then dump them in the app. I have been battling with mapServer for days now. Mapfile can generate raster type files without any hustle but i can not do the same with my shapefiles or any other file for that matter. What am I missing. Here is my mapfile code....

```
MAP
        IMAGETYPE PNG
        NAME "Mapfile"
        EXTENT 15.8278 -35.0547 52.2894 -21.929
        SIZE 2000 1700
    SHAPEPATH "/var/www/html/mapserver/mapfile"
        IMAGECOLOR 128 0 250

        WEB
        Template "/var/www/html/mapserver/mapfile/tamplate.html" #Do not mind the spelling
            IMAGEPATH "/var/www/html/mapserver/outputs/"
            IMAGEURL "../mapserver/outputs/"
        METADATA
                    "wms_title" "Moz_Floods_Before"
                    #"wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?mode=map&map=/var/www/html/mapserver/mapfile/before.map&"
                    "wms_enable_request" "*"
                    "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
        END
        END  
    LAYER
        NAME 'KML_File'  #KML file is the shapefile
        DATA KML_Shape
        STATUS ON
        TYPE POLYGON 
        PROJECTION
                "proj=longlat"
                "ellps=WGS84"
                "datum=WGS84"
                "no_defs"
        END
    END
END
```

This can only display imagecolor..., I',m working on Linux

Comment: You have not defined any style for the vector layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't seem to work, do you have a working code for mapserver and share with me maybe that will assist...

Answer (score 1):

Try below sample (tested). It's possible I missed to remove some parameters not required. You should be able to correct your own issue in the mapfile.

A `sample.map` file

```
MAP
  NAME "MAPSERVER QUICKSTART"
  EXTENT -137 29 -53 88
  UNITS DD
  SHAPEPATH "/tmp/"
  SIZE 800 600
  SYMBOLSET "symbols.txt"
  IMAGETYPE PNG24
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END
  WEB
    METADATA
      ows_enable_request "*"
    END
  END
  LAYER
    NAME "kml_example"
    TYPE POINT
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "uefa-2012.kml"
    DATA "Layer #0"
    CLASS
      NAME "My Places"
      STYLE
        COLOR 246 241 223
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 0 0
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 20
      END
    END
  END
END
```

The `symbols.txt` content

```
SYMBOLSET

SYMBOL
  NAME "circle"
  TYPE ellipse
  FILLED true
  POINTS
    1 1
  END # POINTS
END # SYMBOL

END
```

The link to [kml sample uefa-2012.kml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/generate-kml/kml/uefa-2012.kml)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to display the shapefiles and other files except KML, what is the Layer or where is it defined ('Layers #0')...

Comment: Just do an `ogrinfo -so uefa-2012.kml` and you will see ;)